# Is there any way of finding the most searched keywords in Search Engine from a specific location (not country wise)?

Tags: google-search, search-engines, keywords, bing

Is there any way of finding the most searched keywords in Search Engine from a specific location (not country wise) ?

For e.g.

In google trend , I can find the top search keywords

Country wise : India
Year : 2015

But not Specific Location : "Mumbai"

Can any one demystify on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting Country name just put the city name, like Mumbai or Delhi.

[image]

And choose the product category/sub-category option one by one to explore all the keywords.

[image]